# prove that if $X$ is closed and $f^{-1}(X)$ is closed then f is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function. Show that the three affirmations below are equivalent
>
> - $f$ is a continuous function;
> - for every $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ open $f^{-1}(X)$ is open;
> - for every $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ closed, $f^{-1}(X)$ is closed;

What I must do is show $(1) \implies (2)\implies (3)\implies (1)$.

### $(1)\implies (2)$

Assume $f$ is continuous and $X$ is open.

let $a \in f^{-1}(X)\implies f(a) \in X \implies \exists \epsilon>0$ s.t. $[f(a)-\epsilon,f(a)+\epsilon]\subseteq X$.

Let f is continuous, then, exists $\delta>0$ such that if $x \in [a-\delta,a+\delta] \implies |f(x)-f(a)|\leq \epsilon \implies f(x)\in [f(a)-\epsilon,f(a)+\epsilon]$

which means $f(x) \in X \implies x \in f^{-1}(X)$. So $[a-\delta,a+\delta] \subseteq f^{-1}(X)$

therefore $f^{-1}(X)$ is open.

### $(2) \implies (3)$

Assume $X$ is closed.

$\mathbb{R}\backslash X$ is open $\implies $ $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\backslash X)$ is open $\implies \mathbb{R}\backslash f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\backslash X)$ is closed.

$\mathbb{R}\backslash f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\backslash X) = \{a \in \mathbb{R}|f(a)\not\in \mathbb{R}\backslash X \} = \{a \in \mathbb{R}|f(a)\in X \} = f^{-1}(X)$

therefore $f^{-1}(X)$ is closed.

### $(3)\implies(1)$

Now, what do I do about the third part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$, and let $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Consider the closed set $X = \mathbb R \backslash (f(a)-\epsilon,f(a)+\epsilon)$.

Then, $f^{-1}(X)$ is closed, hence, $\mathbb R \backslash (f^{-1}(X))$ is open.

Note that $f(a) \notin X$, so that $a \in \mathbb R \backslash (f^{-1}(X))$.

As this set is open, we can find a ball of radius $\delta$ around $a$ inside this set.

Now, if $|x-a| < \delta$, then $x \in \mathbb R \backslash (f^{-1}(X))$, so $f(x) \in (f(a)-\epsilon,f(a)+\epsilon)$, so that $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$.

This completes the proof. The other two proofs are correct, by the way.